# uwsgi - harakiri workers with broken pipes

Tags: uwsgi

Is it possible to configure uwsgi to kill workers with broken pipes?

The reason: 
 - we are using server-sent events (events are form a pubsub service);
 - when client disconnects, there is no way to terminate the subscription, and the server process writes to uWSGI, which tries to write to a closed connection.

Until we find a way to gracefully terminate subscriptions, we are looking for a workaround by killing that workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since uWSGI 1.4 every request is interrupted on write errors (an I/O exception is injected too)

Maybe you are using an old uWSGI version

Comment: I was really using uwsgi 1.0.x (a debian package). I have updated uwsgi to 1.9.17.1 (via pip), will monitor logs for a while. Hope it helps, thank You in advance!